# ShellToast.NavigationUri ignored - the toast takes me to MainPage.xaml // WP7.1 Mango

Tags: scheduled-tasks, toast, windows-phone-7, navigateuri

I've been playing with the background tasks and everything is fine (but bizzar), but now I try to do something like this:

```
    protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
    {
        if (task is PeriodicTask)
        {
            ShellToast t = new ShellToast();
            t.Content = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
            t.Title = "mytitle";
            t.NavigationUri = new Uri("/GotHereFromToastLink.xaml?someParam=" + 123, UriKind.Relative);

            t.Show();
        }

        NotifyComplete();
    }
```

Which SHOULD take me to **GoHereFromToastLink.xaml** when I press the toast notification, but instead it always takes me to **MainPage.xaml** - anybody knows if this is a bug? Or am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: is anything passed to the query string when you this navigates to MainPage.xaml?

Comment: nope, nothing... sadly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting some really helpful MS guys I got a response - It's a known issue (aka bug) and it's already fixed but they don't have a date on the update to the Mango SDK but this will be working properly in the final release of the Mango toolset.

So for now - just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem!
Found out that the reason is the relative URI. I assume you have used another absolute URI in your application?

Comment: tried the absolute param, but that throws exception that "resource can't be found" - or something like that... besides - how would a absolute url look like? bacause with how it's written it throws exception when trying to create Uri